# Forming mongo query from String

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I am using mongo-parse to parse the mongo queries. Below is my code

```
var parser = require('mongo-parse')
var queryObject = parser.parse({"city":"Paris"})
//Getting field and value separately
//Field = city
//Value = Paris

var string = 'db.employee.find({"city":"Paris"},{"emp_id":1}'
//Not able to get the field and value separately from string
```

Is there any node module to generate the mongo query from the above string.

Any help on this will be really helpful

Comment: It wont get the client(db) or the collection, those have to be hard coded in a self generated client connection, but mongo-qp can create the filter for you from string

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't look like mongo-parse returns any information about the collection. considering this, couldn't you just take the analysis you get from the parser and hand-construct the query from the data (assuming i'm understanding your question correctly)

e.g.

```
var newQuery = {};
newQuery[queryObject.field] = queryObject.value;
db.employee.find(newQuery, {emp_id: 1});
```